# How to Send export excel or CSV in email from MS Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate, dynamics-365

Everyday I am downloading report in excel exports from Dynamics 365 manually. Is there anyway I can setup a flow setting so that I will get email that report on everyday basis?

Comment: as mentioned in answer from @zach Mast.
I would put my 2 cents on 3rd option. I did implemented this few days back and works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For On-Premise CRM you can schedule reports within the application, this option is not available in CRM online. Here is an old article on the subject:
https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/06/29/report-scheduling-and-email-subscription-in-crm-2011/

There are inexpensive third party utilities which deliver excel view exports on a scheduled basis. I recommend the Work 365 Report Scheduler (formerly IOTAP):
https://online.work365apps.com/work-365-report-scheduler

If you have a .NET developer or partner you can develop a custom workflow step which renders reports as PDF documents and attaches them to emails within an out of the box workflow. Here is an article on the subject:
http://xrmmatrix.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/creating-report-as-pdf-attachment-in.html

Comment: I did implemented 3rd option and this works fine for me. Perfect